# Create temporary file during setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging

I'm having fun with python packaging today. i want to populate the `__version__` keyword in my package, but only when it's pip install'd. if I'm using it locally, then I want the version to come from `git describe`. So what i have is this:

```
def get_version():
    """
    Get the version for the ground station. If the __version__.py exists, it uses the version in there. Otherwise
    it uses the git describe version
    """
    try:
        from . import __version__
        return __version__.__version__
    except ImportError:
        return get_git_tag()


def get_git_tag():
    """Return string of latest (annotated) git tag"""
    version = subprocess.check_output(["git", "describe", "--dirty", "--long"]).decode()
    version = version.rstrip()
    return version
```

which works great. But I want to make sure `__version__.py` only exists on released versions, not in my working repo--and I don't want to risk having a `__version__.py` leak into my development workspace.

So at this point, I'm researching ways to create a file in setup.py that will only exist in the distrubuted version of my package. Any have any tips or warnings as i do this?

Comment: `setup.py` of which packaging tool? py2exe? pyinstaller? cxfreeze? I use to package extra files myself when I create a .zip archive. In that case, I add a buffer to the archive where the file is supposed to be without creating that file on disk, that solves your problem :)

Comment: oh, i definitely need this to be automated. while easy to add the file manually, it's time consuming and error prone

Comment: my script is a python script, so it's automated. I wanted to know which setup you're refereing to. Can you show your setup code?

Comment: i simply call `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`